# Error Going from Entity Framework Code First to DB First

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, entity-framework, api

I have a tutorial book that builds an MVC API app using code first.  I want to use DB first.  When I run the call to the api, it's telling me in the inner exception that it can't find "dbo.".  I suspect that the .dbo is the problem and that if it was dropped (or if I pre-pended that somewhere) it would work, but I can't see where to alter the code to do that.

Here is the whole error I am getting, what I referred to up above is referenced in $id: "3"

> $id: "1", Message: "An error has occurred.", ExceptionMessage: "The
>   'ObjectContent`1' type failed to serialize the response body for
>   content type 'application/json; charset=utf-8'.", ExceptionType:
>   "System.InvalidOperationException", StackTrace: null, InnerException:
>   { $id: "2", Message: "An error has occurred.", ExceptionMessage: "An
>   error occurred while executing the command definition. See the inner
>   exception for details.", ExceptionType:
>   "System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityCommandExecutionException", StackTrace:
>   " at
>   System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityClient.Internal.EntityCommandDefinition.ExecuteStoreCommands(EntityCommand
>   entityCommand, CommandBehavior behavior) at
>   System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.Internal.ObjectQueryExecutionPlan.Execute[TResultType](ObjectContext
>   context, ObjectParameterCollection parameterValues) at
>   System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectQuery`1.<>c__DisplayClass7.b__6()
>   at
>   System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectContext.ExecuteInTransaction[T](Func`1
>   func, IDbExecutionStrategy executionStrategy, Boolean
>   startLocalTransaction, Boolean releaseConnectionOnSuccess) at
>   System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectQuery`1.<>c__DisplayClass7.b__5()
>   at
>   System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.DefaultSqlExecutionStrategy.Execute[TResult](Func`1
>   operation) at
>   System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectQuery`1.GetResults(Nullable`1
>   forMergeOption) at
>   System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectQuery`1..GetEnumerator>b__0()
>   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyEnumerator`1.MoveNext() at
>   Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalWriter.SerializeList(JsonWriter
>   writer, IEnumerable values, JsonArrayContract contract, JsonProperty
>   member, JsonContainerContract collectionContract, JsonProperty
>   containerProperty) at
>   Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalWriter.SerializeValue(JsonWriter
>   writer, Object value, JsonContract valueContract, JsonProperty member,
>   JsonContainerContract containerContract, JsonProperty
>   containerProperty) at
>   Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalWriter.Serialize(JsonWriter
>   jsonWriter, Object value, Type objectType) at
>   Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializer.SerializeInternal(JsonWriter
>   jsonWriter, Object value, Type objectType) at
>   System.Net.Http.Formatting.BaseJsonMediaTypeFormatter.WriteToStream(Type
>   type, Object value, Stream writeStream, Encoding effectiveEncoding) at
>   System.Net.Http.Formatting.JsonMediaTypeFormatter.WriteToStream(Type
>   type, Object value, Stream writeStream, Encoding effectiveEncoding) at
>   System.Net.Http.Formatting.BaseJsonMediaTypeFormatter.WriteToStream(Type
>   type, Object value, Stream writeStream, HttpContent content) at
>   System.Net.Http.Formatting.BaseJsonMediaTypeFormatter.WriteToStreamAsync(Type
>   type, Object value, Stream writeStream, HttpContent content,
>   TransportContext transportContext, CancellationToken
>   cancellationToken) --- End of stack trace from previous location where
>   exception was thrown --- at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task
>   task) at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task) at
>   System.Web.Http.WebHost.HttpControllerHandler.<WriteBufferedResponseContentAsync>d__1b.MoveNext()",
>   InnerException: { $id: "3", Message: "An error has occurred.",
>   **ExceptionMessage: "Invalid object name 'dbo.ContactType'."**, ExceptionType: "System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException", StackTrace: " at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.OnError(SqlException exception,
>   Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction) at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnection.OnError(SqlException
>   exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction) at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning(TdsParserStateObject
>   stateObj, Boolean callerHasConnectionLock, Boolean asyncClose) at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.TryRun(RunBehavior runBehavior,
>   SqlCommand cmdHandler, SqlDataReader dataStream,
>   BulkCopySimpleResultSet bulkCopyHandler, TdsParserStateObject
>   stateObj, Boolean& dataReady) at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.TryConsumeMetaData() at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.get_MetaData() at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.FinishExecuteReader(SqlDataReader ds,
>   RunBehavior runBehavior, String resetOptionsString, Boolean
>   isInternal, Boolean forDescribeParameterEncryption) at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReaderTds(CommandBehavior
>   cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, Boolean
>   async, Int32 timeout, Task& task, Boolean asyncWrite, Boolean inRetry,
>   SqlDataReader ds, Boolean describeParameterEncryptionRequest) at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReader(CommandBehavior
>   cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, String
>   method, TaskCompletionSource`1 completion, Int32 timeout, Task& task,
>   Boolean& usedCache, Boolean asyncWrite, Boolean inRetry) at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReader(CommandBehavior
>   cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, String
>   method) at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior
>   behavior, String method) at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteDbDataReader(CommandBehavior
>   behavior) at
>   System.Data.Common.DbCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior behavior)
>   at
>   System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.Interception.DbCommandDispatcher.b__c(DbCommand
>   t, DbCommandInterceptionContext`1 c) at
>   System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.Interception.InternalDispatcher`1.Dispatch[TTarget,TInterceptionContext,TResult](TTarget
>   target, Func`3 operation, TInterceptionContext interceptionContext,
>   Action`3 executing, Action`3 executed) at
>   System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.Interception.DbCommandDispatcher.Reader(DbCommand
>   command, DbCommandInterceptionContext interceptionContext) at
>   System.Data.Entity.Internal.InterceptableDbCommand.ExecuteDbDataReader(CommandBehavior
>   behavior) at
>   System.Data.Common.DbCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior behavior)
>   at
>   System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityClient.Internal.EntityCommandDefinition.ExecuteStoreCommands(EntityCommand
>   entityCommand, CommandBehavior behavior)"

DBContext.edmx

```
<EntityType Name="ContactType">
  <Key>
    <PropertyRef Name="ID" />
  </Key>
  <Property Name="ID" Type="int" StoreGeneratedPattern="Identity" Nullable="false" />
  <Property Name="Description" Type="varchar" MaxLength="50" Nullable="false" />
</EntityType>
```

DBContext.Context.cs

```
public virtual DbSet<ContactType> ContactType { get; set; }

public virtual int addContact(Nullable<int> contactTypeID, string emailAddress, string lastName, string firstName, string companyName, string phoneNumber1, string phoneNumber2, string comment)
{
    var contactTypeIDParameter = contactTypeID.HasValue ?
        new ObjectParameter("ContactTypeID", contactTypeID) :
        new ObjectParameter("ContactTypeID", typeof(int));

    var emailAddressParameter = emailAddress != null ?
        new ObjectParameter("EmailAddress", emailAddress) :
        new ObjectParameter("EmailAddress", typeof(string));

    var lastNameParameter = lastName != null ?
        new ObjectParameter("LastName", lastName) :
        new ObjectParameter("LastName", typeof(string));

    var firstNameParameter = firstName != null ?
        new ObjectParameter("FirstName", firstName) :
        new ObjectParameter("FirstName", typeof(string));

    var companyNameParameter = companyName != null ?
        new ObjectParameter("CompanyName", companyName) :
        new ObjectParameter("CompanyName", typeof(string));

    var phoneNumber1Parameter = phoneNumber1 != null ?
        new ObjectParameter("PhoneNumber1", phoneNumber1) :
        new ObjectParameter("PhoneNumber1", typeof(string));

    var phoneNumber2Parameter = phoneNumber2 != null ?
        new ObjectParameter("PhoneNumber2", phoneNumber2) :
        new ObjectParameter("PhoneNumber2", typeof(string));

    var commentParameter = comment != null ?
        new ObjectParameter("Comment", comment) :
        new ObjectParameter("Comment", typeof(string));

    return ((IObjectContextAdapter)this).ObjectContext.ExecuteFunction("addContact", contactTypeIDParameter, emailAddressParameter, lastNameParameter, firstNameParameter, companyNameParameter, phoneNumber1Parameter, phoneNumber2Parameter, commentParameter);
}
```

ContactType.cs

```
namespace AHT.Data
{
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;

    public partial class ContactType
    {
        [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2214:DoNotCallOverridableMethodsInConstructors")]
        public ContactType()
        {
            this.Contact = new HashSet<Contact>();
        }

        public int ID { get; set; }
        public string Description { get; set; }

        [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
        public virtual ICollection<Contact> Contact { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you post the code you use to get this data from database using EntityFramework? Posting this `ContactType` and the generated code for your DbContext (specifically the part which deals with your `ContactType` entity) would also help.

Comment: I added the references to the original post at the bottom

Answer (score 0):

Please disregard, this was a stupid config string error.

Comment: You can delete your question.